# How to count hypothenuses with pandas udf, pyspark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I want to write a panda udf which will take two arguments cathetus1, and cathetus2 from other dataframe and return hypot.

```
# this data is list where cathetuses are.
data = [(3.0, 4.0), (6.0, 8.0), (3.3, 5.6)]
schema = StructType([StructField("cathetus1",DoubleType(),True),StructField("cathetus2",DoubleType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.show()
#and this is creating dataframe where only cathetuses are showing.
```

this is function i have written so far.

```
def pandaUdf(cat1, cat2):
  leg1 = []
  leg2 = []
  for i in data: 
    x = 0 
    leg1.append(i[x])
    leg2.append(i[x+1])
    hypoData.append(np.hypot(leg1,leg2))
  return np.hypot(leg1,leg2)

#example_series = pd.Series(data)
```

and im trying to create a new column in df, which values will be hypos.

```
df.withColumn(col('Hypo'), pandaUdf(example_df.cathetus1,example_df.cathetus2)).show()
```

but this gives me an error --> col should be Column.

I dont understand how I can fix this error or why its even there.

Comment: You need to define the function as `pandas_udf`. Also, the first parameter for `.withColumn` must be a string which is the column name not a `Column` expression. Please read the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) on how to create and use pandas_udf in pyspark.

Comment: I've read that documentation but im still confused as to why I have that error.

Comment: I'm not sure why a pandas_udf is required. Can't we use pyspark.sql.functions (pow and sqrt)?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `np.hypot` on the 2 `cathetus` directly without extracting individual values.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [(3.0, 4.0), (6.0, 8.0), (3.3, 5.6)]
schema = StructType([StructField("cathetus1",DoubleType(),True),StructField("cathetus2",DoubleType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.show()

"""
+---------+---------+
|cathetus1|cathetus2|
+---------+---------+
|      3.0|      4.0|
|      6.0|      8.0|
|      3.3|      5.6|
+---------+---------+
"""

def hypot(cat1: pd.Series, cat2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return np.hypot(cat1,cat2)

hypot_pandas_df = F.pandas_udf(hypot, returnType=FloatType())

df.withColumn("Hypo", hypot_pandas_df("cathetus1", "cathetus2")).show()

"""
+---------+---------+----+
|cathetus1|cathetus2|Hypo|
+---------+---------+----+
|      3.0|      4.0| 5.0|
|      6.0|      8.0|10.0|
|      3.3|      5.6| 6.5|
+---------+---------+----+
"""
```